# php file doesn't work

Tags: php, linux, apache

i have problem with php on my dedicated server

apache2 doesen't want to execute php files

when i try to open my site in browser 
for example mysite.com/index.php

my browser just downloaded file index.php

any suggestions?

here my php.conf

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so
</IfModule>

AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

DirectoryIndex index.php

AddType Application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Answer (score 0):

In my http.conf I have this. Obviously the path are different but this can help. About php I have no more than this 3 lines:

```
LoadModule php5_module PATH/TO/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PhpIniDir "PATH/TO/PHP"
```

So I think you can delete all your lines about php and try to just add these.